# How to convert Visual Studio C++ Managed Test Project To Native Unit Test Project easily?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

In Visual Studio 2012 Microsoft introduced Native Unit Testing for C++. Currently I have thousands of legacy Unit tests in the older 'Managed Test Project' format. Is there an easy way to convert/transfer the unit tests in the Managed Test Projects into Native Unit Test Projects ?

Comment: Are your "Managed Test Project" tests Managed C++ or native C++? I don't think you can just convert managed to native.

Comment: @Dan, the test code is managed C++ (Managed Test Project is the name given in the wizard), testing pure C++ classes. I was hoping someone made regexes, or Microsoft created a not-well known tool to convert the code.